# how to design the col in boostrap 3.3.6?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web

How can I design this image below using Bootstrap 3.3.6, those are div CSS? I am just a new programmer, hope you can help me.

[image]

Comment: try to do some code from your end and come with issue then we can help. On SO no one will serve you ready made code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do using divs.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <body>
   <div style="border:3px solid black; width:auto; padding:10px;">
    <div style="border:3px solid blue; width:auto; padding:10px; text-align:center;">
     <div style="width:100px; display:inline-block; border:3px solid pink; margin:10px; height:10px; padding:10px;">
     </div>
     <div style="width:100px; display:inline-block; border:3px solid green; margin:10px; height:10px; padding:10px;">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </head>
<html>
```

To get the two inner-most divs floating side-by-side, we use display:inline-block; property.

Answer (score 0):

use this. this is a bootstrap code.

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should look like that :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div-1 col-md-12">
      <div class="div-2 col-md-12">
        <div class="div-3 col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="div-4 col-md-6">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After that the css will do the trick